# Has aloe vera been proven to help heal burned skin areas?

Tags: skin

I don't like buying into "natural remedy" type things without seeing scientific proof behind them. There's an almost universal belief that aloe vera helps to heal burned skin, and whether that includes assisting in cell regrowth, preventing inflamation, or something else, I haven't bedn able to find any real scientific evidence.

Can anyone cite legitimate scientific evidence that aloe vera has any helpful effect for burned skin? If so, how does it work?

Comment: No, there is no reliable proof of its effectiveness (if I remember correctly, one decent study found delayed healing.) And I actually *like* "natural remedies", which is why I look for supporting studies. But you might cite a source and ask on Skeptics.SE.

Comment: A quick Google Scholar search gave me this [paper](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/26059618/05_wound_healing.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1493567833&Signature=dlDx7vln7JYw06niKRcEUT%2FzllY%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DWound_Healing_Oral_and_Topical_Activity.pdf) which is a list of abstract of research that suggests it helps with would healing, inflammation and burn wounds